# Pattern to model wiki-type functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, wiki-engine

Is there a pattern or a gem (Ruby on rails) for modeling the wiki-like behaviour of a StackOverflow like web site?

I'm working on Ruby-on-Rails project so a gem or something in RoR would be appreciated but a well defined pattern is just as good.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [`act_as_versioned`](http://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned)? It is available as a gem, and adds simple versioning to any ActiveRecord model.

If you need more features, [`act_as_revisable`](http://withoutscope.com/2009/4/3/flexible-activerecord-versioning-with-actsasrevisable) might be interesting. According to the link, it adds the following features on top of `act_as_versioned`:

- Pervasive Callbacks
- Branching and Changesets
- Deletes can be stored as a revision
- Explicit is better than implicit
- All data for a model is stored in one table
- Wrapping up, requirements and installing